# Function Map Positive Measure Set to Positive Measure Set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a function. Let $E\subseteq [0,1]$, such that $\mu(E)>0$. What conditions on $f$ would guarantee that $f(E)$ is also measurable, and $\mu(f(E))>0$?

I guess that $f$ should be measurable and continuous bijection, but this is not the correct condition.

Comment: Do you mean, what condition would ensure that *for all* measurable $E$ with positive measure, $f(E)$ is measurable with positive measure?

Comment: Correct. That is more precise.

Comment: It would suffice for $f$ to be bijective such that $f^{-1}$ is absolutely continuous, but this is not necessary.  E.g., $(2x-1)^2$ is not bijective but satisfies the condition.